# Insert line breaks in VariableReplace in docx4j

Tags: docx4j

I have been trying to fill up a word template(.docx) file which has placeholders which needs to be replaced.

I was able to rewrite the template but the text does not come with line breaks
I understand that carriage return or new line (\r\n) does not work in .docx files. I used the VariableReplace method to convert but I was unable to place br or factory.createBr() while using the variable replace.

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Below is the piece of code what i tried

```
    Map<String,String> variableReplaceMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> textContent = readTextContentAfterDBExtractionToFillUpTemplate();
    ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
    P para = factory.createP();
    R rspc = factory.createR();

    String power= textContent.get("Power & Energy");
    String[] powerWithNewLine = skills.split("\\\\n");
    for (String eachLineOfPower : powerWithNewLine) {

        Text eachLineOfPowerTxt = factory.createText();
        eachLineOfPowerTxt .setValue( eachLineOfPower );
        rspc.getContent().add( eachLineOfPowerTxt );
        Br br = factory.createBr(); 
        rspc.getContent().add(br);
        para.getParagraphContent().add(rspc);
        documentPart.addObject(para);
    }
    String str = "";
    for (Object eachLineOfPgrph : para.getParagraphContent()) {
        str = str + eachLineOfPgrph;
    }
    variableReplaceMap.put("POWER", str);
    return variableReplaceMap;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See newlineToBreakHack method at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java#L122

Answer (score 3):

The link from Jason is dead.
Here is the current link: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java

In case it gets changed in the future, simply use the following function and apply it to your string, that contains linebreaks:

```
/**
 * Hack to convert a new line character into w:br.
 * If you need this sort of thing, consider using 
 * OpenDoPE content control data binding instead.
 *  
 * @param r
 * @return
 */
private static String newlineToBreakHack(String r) {

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(r, "\n\r\f"); // tokenize on the newline character, the carriage-return character, and the form-feed character
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    
    boolean firsttoken = true;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {                        
        String line = (String) st.nextToken();
        if (firsttoken) {
            firsttoken = false;
        } else {
            sb.append("</w:t><w:br/><w:t>");
        }
        sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();   
}
```