# Insert line break in docx4j with variable replacement

Tags: java, docx4j

I have a template with certain variables that I need to replace with info from my database, basically.
when I just want to replace with a word it's easy, my problem is when I need to break line like this:
[image]

This two persons with their CPF's should come from my variable, but that's what I'm getting:
[image]

That's my code now, I've tried putting "\n", "
" and "<w:\br>", and none of them worked, now I'm putting "\n" just to be clear where I want to break line:

```
private String criaIdentificacaoAssistenciaSocial(Lote lote) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder identificacaoAS = new StringBuilder();
    for (Pessoa pessoa : lote.getJsonBeneficiarios()) {
        PessoaFisica beneficiario = (PessoaFisica) pessoa;
        identificacaoAS.append(beneficiario.getNome()).append(", CPF ").append(beneficiario.getCpf());
        identificacaoAS.append("\n");
        if (beneficiario.getConjuge() != null) {
            identificacaoAS.append(beneficiario.getConjuge().getNome()).append(", CPF ").append(beneficiario.getConjuge().getCpf());
            identificacaoAS.append("\n");
        }
    }
    return identificacaoAS.toString();
}
```

My return value goes inside my mappingDocsVariable, then I generate the docx file with this code:

```
private File geraDocumento(HashMap<String, String> mappingDocVariables, String nomeDocx) throws Exception {
    String inputfilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator
            + "utils" + File.separator + nomeDocx + ".docx";

    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new java.io.File(inputfilepath));
    MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
    VariablePrepare.prepare(wordMLPackage);
    documentPart.variableReplace(mappingDocVariables);
    String tDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    File temp = new File(tDir + nomeDocx + ".docx");
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, temp);
    temp.deleteOnExit();
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: It's probably a typo in your description but it should be <w:br/> and not <w:\br> as you mentioned :-) Also did you checked this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44135393/docx4j-insert-a-line-break ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See newlineToBreakHack at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java#L122

Previously answered at [Insert line breaks in VariableReplace in docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190844/insert-line-breaks-in-variablereplace-in-docx4j)